# CentOS 7 timing out while yum update

Tags: centos, security, vmware-esxi, yum

I have been going with this error for the past couple of days. When I do a "yum update" or basically any "yum" command, it is timing out and taking a real long time or basically stop it. I went everyone on Google to find solutions and none of them were any help. Here is my set-up:

VMware ESXI 6.5 Host
It's a CentOS 7 virtual machine
Running on OVH network.

Here is what it's giving me when I do a yum update...

```
Total download size: 100 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/packages/NetworkManager-libnm-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for NetworkManager-libnm-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/71): NetworkManager-libnm-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm     | 443 kB   00:00     
(2/71): NetworkManager-team-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm      | 147 kB   00:00     
NetworkManager-tui-1.4.0-20.el FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/NetworkManager-tui-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
(3/71): NetworkManager-wifi-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm      | 176 kB   00:00     
NetworkManager-1.4.0-20.el7_3. FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/NetworkManager-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/NetworkManager-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
(4/71): audit-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm                   | 233 kB   00:00     
(5/71): audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm              |  85 kB   00:00     
bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64.rp FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
(6/71): bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-38.el7_3.3.x86_64.rpm         | 730 kB   00:00     
(7/71): bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.3.noarch.rpm           |  83 kB   00:00     
(8/71): ca-certificates-2017.2.14-70.1.el7_3.noarch.rpm    | 438 kB   00:00     
(9/71): chkconfig-1.7.2-1.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm               | 175 kB   00:00     
(10/71): chrony-2.1.1-4.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm              | 281 kB   00:00     
device-mapper-1.02.135-1.el7_3 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/device-mapper-1.02.135-1.el7_3.5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/device-mapper-1.02.135-1.el7_3.5.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1. FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.5.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 30540 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
dmidecode-3.0-2.1.el7_3.x86_64 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/dmidecode-3.0-2.1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: centos.mirror.iweb.ca; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
dracut-033-463.el7_3.2.x86_64. FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/dracut-033-463.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/dracut-033-463.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 30539 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
dracut-config-rescue-033-463.e FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/dracut-config-rescue-033-463.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
firewalld-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3. FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.colo-serv.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/firewalld-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:19c0:e:13::23: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
firewalld-filesystem-0.4.3.2-8 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.vexxhost.com/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/firewalld-filesystem-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2604:e100:1:0:f816:3eff:fe28:88d0: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
(11/71): gawk-4.0.2-4.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm                   | 874 kB   00:00     
(12/71): glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.4.x86_64.rpm                 | 3.6 MB   00:00     
expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64.rp FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.netelligent.ca/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.netelligent.ca/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
grubby-8.28-21.el7_3.x86_64.rp FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/grubby-8.28-21.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
(13/71): irqbalance-1.0.7-6.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm             |  44 kB   00:00     
(14/71): kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.rpm             |  37 MB   00:01     
(15/71): kernel-tools-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.rpm       | 4.0 MB   00:00     
dracut-network-033-463.el7_3.2 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/dracut-network-033-463.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/dracut-network-033-463.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 30539 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.4. FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.netelligent.ca/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.4.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.netelligent.ca/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.4.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
initscripts-9.49.37-1.el7_3.1. FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/initscripts-9.49.37-1.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
krb5-libs-1.14.1-27.el7_3.x86_ FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/krb5-libs-1.14.1-27.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.2 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
kpartx-0.4.9-99.el7_3.3.x86_64 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/kpartx-0.4.9-99.el7_3.3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
(16/71): libblkid-2.23.2-33.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm             | 170 kB   00:10     
libgcrypt-1.5.3-13.el7_3.1.x86 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/libgcrypt-1.5.3-13.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
libgudev1-219-30.el7_3.9.x86_6 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/libgudev1-219-30.el7_3.9.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/libgudev1-219-30.el7_3.9.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
(17/71): libmount-2.23.2-33.el7_3.2.x86_64.rpm             | 172 kB   00:00     
libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.6-1 FAILED                                          
http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.6-1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.6-1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
(18/71): libnl3-3.2.28-3.el7_3.x86_64.rpm                  | 278 kB   00:00
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Looks to be a IPv6 connection issue (add ip_resolve=ipv4 to /etc/yum.conf to force only IPv4). Of that doesn't work it may be the gpg key validation failing. Give the IPv4 option a try.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that IPv6 is not correctly configured on your VPS. You should finish configuring IPv6 on the VPS (contact OVH for help with this).

Answer (score -1):

Check internet connection and bandwidth too and Try this:

```
yum clean all
yum check
yum erase apf
yum upgrade
```